# "graph-paper" style for z=0 plane in a 3D plot

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I'm looking to get publication-quality illustrations in the style of "Interactive Linear Algebra" [book](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/systems-of-eqns.html) where z=0 plane has the look of graph-paper

[image]

What is a good pattern to achieve this effect?

```
circle = RegionPlot3D[{0.4 < x^2 + y^2 < .5}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, 0, .1}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 75, Boxed -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Comment: You can try this: ``Show[plot1, Plot3D[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 5]]``. The mesh density is controlled by the ``Mesh`` option.

Answer (score 8):

```
Histogram3D[CirclePoints[20000], Axes -> False, Boxed -> Bottom, 
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm getting something close by using a combination of Mesh, MeshStyle, BoundaryStyle and Arrow primitives.

downsides:

1. intersection artifacts between Arrow objects and the solid
2. bottom part of arrow is not occluded properly

```
th = 0.0015;
plot = RegionPlot3D[{0.4 < x^2 + y^2 < .5}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
    1}, {z, 0, .1}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 75, Boxed -> False, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Thickness[th]];
arrows = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], Thickness[th], 
    Arrow[{{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}]}];
plane = Plot3D[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> None, 
   Mesh -> 5, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.001], Opacity[.2]], 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[th], Opacity[.2]]];
img = Show[plot, arrows, plane, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Edit**
Axis occlusion artifacts are fixed with `"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"`, however it introduces occlusion artifacts within the solid. Seen in default Viewpoint, but much more visible under `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`

[image]

Using `RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}` fixes the occlusion artifacts, but now diagonal axes have rendering artifacts.

[image]

On MacOS having a 3D graphic cell with non-default rendering method introduces 1-2 second "spinning beach ball" hangs, so use these options for export only

Comment: In the end, best results with `"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"` and avoiding `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`